# How to make the following code to work in mobile template of blogger

Tags: html

This conditional code is works well when viewed from a desktop browser, but I would like this to work as a mobile site as well. Please suggest any modifications required.

Step- 1 **Below**  `</b:skin>` pasted the following code-

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url !=
&quot;http://yourblog.blogspot.com/search/label/Label&quot;'>
<style>
#Gadgetid{
display: none;
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

Step-2 Below`<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>` pasted the following code:

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;index&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Label&quot;'>
    <style>
    #gadgetid{
    display: block !important;
    }
    </style>
    </b:if>
    </b:if>
```

Comment: still not working in mobile template

Comment: Working only in desktop browser...Still not in mobile version..

Answer (score 0):

Try using @media rule in css. I think that will work.

Comment: how did you implemented @media. Can you provide any snippet.

Comment: Search For ]]></b:skin> and pasted @media (max-width:728px) {
#Gadgetid {display:none!important;}
} Inside that Skin in Pasted.